# Unix - issue with bash for Y/N answer

Tags: unix

I've currently created a unix bash which asks for a Y/N input, i have then created code for if the user types y or n. But if the user types something else, it'll come up with an echo of "Please enter Y or N" how do i then redirect it so goes back to the original Y/N input?

```
 #! /bin/bash

    echo "Do you want to change the directory? Y/N?"
    read answer
    if [[ $answer == "y" || $answer == "Y" ]]; then
    echo "Yes"
    elif [[ $answer == "n" || $answer == "N" ]]; then
    echo "No"
    else
    echo "Please enter Y or N"
    #redirect back to "Do you want to change the directory" echo
    fi
```

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: Just added in the code-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

to_do=true

while $to_do;
do
    read -p "Do you want to change the directory? Y/N " answer
    case $answer in
        [Yy]*)
            echo Yes
            to_do=false
            ;;
        [Nn]*)
            echo No
            to_do=false
            ;;
        *)
            echo Please enter Y or N
    esac
done
```

Comment: you could use `read -p 'Do you want to change the directory? Y/N' answer` as well

Comment: I don't entirely understand the edit? Why are the quotes needed?

Comment: Works just as i wanted it to. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickCollins - run the original code in a directory containing something named `directoryfoo`.  Without the quotes, the `directory?` will result in a pattern match on the file system.

Comment: @D.Shawley Ah, okay. I made your suggested edit, thanks for teaching me something new!

Comment: Does the semi-colon at the end of the line containing the WHILE statement, serve any purpose ? From what I know, it means : now there's a statement following - written on the same line - but to be executed as if it was a new line.

Comment: What does the -p do to it?

Comment: @James111 It just allows text to be displayed close to the cursor waiting for user input.